# How to add a TextInput to NSAlert in Swift ?

Tags: swift, textinput

How can i add a TextInput to "myPopup" in this example?
is there a .PlainTextInput for NS as there is for the NI classes?

```
    let myPopup: NSAlert = NSAlert()
    myPopup.messageText = "Text Entry"
```